# SQLSTATE[HY000]: errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I try to make migration
and my error is "errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"
I cant explain more than this but I should write smt for stack validate length

and its my code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bus_lines', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title',20)->collation('utf8_persian_ci');
        $table->unsignedInteger('code');
        $table->integer('start_station');
        $table->integer('end_station');
        $table->smallInteger('pub');
        $table->smallInteger('rmv');
        $table->timestamps();

        });
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('station_buses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title',30);
        $table->unsignedInteger('code');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('busline_stationbus', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('line_code');
        $table->unsignedInteger('station_code');
        $table->timestamps();


        $table->foreign('line_code')->references('code')->on('bus_lines')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('station_code')->references('code')->on('station_buses')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if the foreign key is applied to a non primary key it has to be applied to a unique column:

> **A FOREIGN KEY** constraint does not have to be linked only to a **PRIMARY KEY** constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference the columns of a **UNIQUE** constraint in another table.

So your `code` in both tables should be this:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('code')->unique();
```